# lidR delineate crown spatial polygon error

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

While using the `delineate_crown` function to delineate crowns, I get a spatial polygon error. How can this be fixed?

```r
# Bring in the ALS file
TP1 = readLAS("~/Sample.las")

# Then, normalize the data so that ground points are centered on 0.
TP1_DTM = grid_terrain(TP1.pmf, algorithm = knnidw(k = 8, p = 2))
TP1.normalized = normalize_height(TP1.pmf, TP1_DTM)

# Create a filter to remove points above 95th percentile of height
filter_noise = function(las, sensitivity)
{
  p99 = grid_metrics(las, ~quantile(Z, probs = 0.99), 10)
  las = merge_spatial(las, p99, "p99")
  las = filter_poi(las, Z < p99*sensitivity)
  las$p99 <- NULL
  return(las)
}

TP1_denoised = filter_noise(TP1.normalized, sensitivity = 1.2)

# Generate the Canopy Height Model (CHM)
TP1.CHM = grid_canopy(TP1_denoised, 0.5, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,20), c(3,1.5), subcircle = 0.2))
plot_dtm3d(TP1.CHM)

# Here a single 5x5 moving window is used to apply a median filter:
win = matrix(1,5,5)
TP1.chm_s = focal(TP1.CHM, w = win, fun = median)

TP1.wtrshd = watershed(TP1.chm_s, th = 20)
TP1.ITD.wtrshd  = segment_trees(TP1_denoised, TP1.wtrshd)

# Hulls from the Watershed method
TP1_hulls_wtrshd  = delineate_crowns(TP1.ITD.wtrshd, func = .stdmetrics)
#> Error in sp::SpatialPolygons(hulls[["poly"]]) : is.list(Srl) is not TRUE
```

This is how the CHM with tree tops (shrubs) look like

[image]

Comment: Impossible to anwser without a reproductible exemple. Looks like a bug with an edge case.

Comment: @JRR Is there a way to share the sample file with you outside this post, as I don't want to share the data here due to privacy?

Comment: Send me an email with a reproducible exemple + a link to the file. You can find my email in the package metadata.

Comment: @JRR, I am sorry, but when I sent the email, I got an error that The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect, so that's I had to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP sent me the file so I was able to reproduce. At this line:

```r
TP1.wtrshd = watershed(TP1.chm_s, th = 20)
```

`th = 20` means that no pixel below 20 can be classified as tree. Here the highest point of your point-cloud being 2.5 it means that no pixel has been classified as tree. The raster computed by `watershed` contains `NA` for each pixel. This lead to an edge case not covered by the package and an unexpected failure in `delineate_crown()`. The following parameters look better.

```r
TP1.wtrshd = watershed(TP1.chm_s, th_tree = 0.5, tol = 0, ext = 1)
#> [...]
plot(TP1.CHM, col = height.colors(50))
plot(TP1_hulls_wtrshd, border = "red", add = T, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Yet, I don't think `watershed()` is the best choice here. Considering that you are using a method for something out of the scope of the function (designed for trees not shrubs) I would use something that allows a better control on the seeds: Something like that:

```r
ttops = find_trees(TP1_denoised, lmf(3, 0.5))
TP1.wtrshd = dalponte2016(TP1.chm_s, ttops, th_tree = 0.5)
#> [...]
plot(TP1.CHM, col = height.colors(50))
plot(TP1_hulls_wtrshd, border = "red", add = T, lwd = 2)
```

[image]