# Point Cloud Z attribute not getting rendered by rayshader

Tags: lidr

I am having some problem with properly plotting the Z values from the LAS file as mentioned here. I am using the latest development version of `lidR` and the latest version of `rayshader` available from GitHub.

```
 # Bring in the LAS file
LAS = readLAS("path/Sample.las")
LAS_Height = readLAS("path/Sample_Height.las")

# Create DTM
LAS_DTM = grid_terrain(LAS_Height,res = 0.1, algorithm = knnidw(k = 8, p = 2))

# Plot it via lidR to see how the DTM looks in 3D
plot_dtm3d(LAS_DTM)
```

[image]

```
# Overlay the LAS height normalized on top of the DTM to plot via lidR
LAS_Height_plot = plot(LAS_Height)
add_dtm3d(LAS_Height_plot, dtm = LAS_DTM)
```

[image]

[image]

```
## Now plotting via rayshader
# First convert the DTM to matrix
LAS_DTM_mat   = raster_to_matrix(LAS_DTM)

# Extent
LAS_Extent = extent(LAS_DTM)

# Create Basemap
LAS_Basemap = LAS_DTM_mat    %>%
  height_shade() %>%
  add_shadow(lamb_shade( LAS_DTM_mat,zscale = 6),0) %>%
  add_overlay(sphere_shade( LAS_DTM_mat, texture = "desert",
                           zscale=4, colorintensity = 5), alphalayer=0.5) %>%
  add_shadow(ambient_shade(LAS_DTM_mat), 0) %>%
  add_shadow(texture_shade(LAS_DTM_mat    ,detail=8/10,contrast=9,brightness = 11), 0.1) 

# Now plot the Basemap in 3D via rayshader
  LAS_Basemap   %>%
  plot_3d(LAS_DTM_mat, windowsize=c(1200,800))
```

[image]

```
# Define the color palette
LAS_pal = colorRampPalette(height.colors(10))
LAS_col = ALS_TP1_pal(30)[as.numeric(cut(LAS_Height$Z, breaks = 30))]

# Render
  LAS_Basemap   %>%
  plot_3d(LAS_DTM_mat, windowsize=c(1200,800))   
render_points(extent = LAS_Extent , long = LAS_Height$X, lat = LAS_Height$Y, altitude = LAS_Height$Z, size = 2, color = LAS_col )
```

[image]

So you see the point cloud is flat for some reason.

How can this be fixed?

On a side note, when I plot the DTM via `rayshader::plot_3d`, the surface appears flat compared to when plotted via `lidr::plot_dtm3d`.

[image]

Comment: The file showed in this question is the same used in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/400663/lidr-delineate-crown-spatial-polygon-error) question.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example. There are too many variables not defined in you example + share the file. The question linked does not contain any file. You sent me the file by email but I deleted it.

Comment: @JRR, kindly check your inbox, I just emailed you the link to the sample files. Hope this helps in reproducing the problem.

Comment: Your code looks correct when tested on another dataset. I did not receive the file. Anyway, you are not supposed to send me a file but to put a link here. This is not **my** forum but a public forum where everybody can answer. Especially here because it seems it is actually a `rayshader` question not a `lidR` question

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the date publicly due to data privacy, so should I cross post this question on stackoverflow then, as `rayshader` doesn't have a tag on this forum? Moreover, is there a problem with the LAS file then?

Comment: Do as you wish. People on stackexchange network are spending time helping others for free. But on your side you must play with the rules that are simple:  *minimal reproducible example*. Your problem not being reproducible with another dataset of mine you must either show your dataset or figure out a way to reproduce with another one.

Comment: @Arthur_Morgan Cross posting is not allowed of SE sites. More details: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/641151